# Use M.2 SSD with SATA drive

Tags: sata, compatibility, m2-connector

I bought a Dell Inspiron 13 5000 2 in 1 laptop, which has a SATA hard drive.

I bought an M.2 SSD to replace the HDD drive. If I use an [M.2 to SATA adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HKV2TVK), will the SSD replacement work? Will there be any decrease in performance because of using the adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a M.2-SSD in a SATA-Port should be possible with the right adaptor. The one you linked should work, although those adaptors are usually cheap electronics, so getting a faulty one is possible and might damage your hardware. You shouldn't notice any performance bottlenecks.

Still, why don't you get a regular SATA SSD? They are often even cheaper than M.2 ones, and you wouldn't need an adaptor. I'd try to return the M.2-SSD for a SATA one before buying an adaptor.